# Using a nameserver provided by KVM host

Tags: dns, kvm, gentoo, maas

My bridge device is set up on the `192.168.1.0/24` network, and my KVM devices are set up on a virtual network (NAT to br0) in the `192.168.100.0/24` network. I have a MAAS server in KVM at `192.168.100.10` which provides DNS services for all my KVM guests. I am trying to ssh to these guests using their hostname, but it is not working.

## /etc/conf.d/net

```
# Set up the initial layer 2 bridge interface
bridge_br0="enp4s0"

# bridge
config_br0="dhcp"

bridge_forward_delay_br0=0
bridge_hello_time_br0=1000
dns_domain="maas"
dns_servers="192.168.1.1 192.168.100.10 8.8.8.8"
dhcp="nodns"
```

## /etc/resolv.conf

```
# Generated by net-scripts for interface br0
domain maas
nameserver 192.168.1.1
nameserver 192.168.100.10
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

## Some Tests

```
damaya@data ~ $ ssh ubuntu@juju.maas
ssh: Could not resolve hostname juju.maas: Name or service not known
damaya@data ~ $ host juju.maas
Host juju.maas not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
damaya@data ~ $ host juju.maas 192.168.100.10
Using domain server:
Name: 192.168.100.10
Address: 192.168.100.10#53
Aliases: 

juju.maas has address 192.168.100.178
```

My question: What network settings do I need in order to allow my host system to be able to use the DNS server provided by MAAS?

Comment: According to your `resolv.conf`, you're contacting 192.168.1.1 before the MAAS server. What's on 192.168.1.1? Also, does the MAAS server contain a recursing DNS resolver, or does it only return queries for the `.maas` domain?